# Changing Menu Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the background-image for a menu button once it is clicked but CSS :active property doesn't work for it, only for while it is being clicked, I need for it to stay as the image until they click it again.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="clearfix">
   <div class="menu">
      <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
         <li>
             <a href="home.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="slide.html">Before/After</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="fac.html">Facilities</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="staff.html">Staff</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="site-wrapper">
      <div class="header">
          <a><div class="menu-trigger" title="Menu"></div></a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script src="testing.js" type="text/javascript">
   </script>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-trigger {
    background-image:url("http://download.seaicons.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-2/512/usb-icon.png");
    background-position:center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    left: -150%;
    transform:rotate(-135deg);
    position:relative;
}

.menu-trigger:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('a .menu-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').toggleClass('open', 300, 'easeOutQuad');
});
```

Comment: Normally this will be no problem, since your menu will be dynamic (pulled from database, or created via array server-side), and you can attach a class to the "active" menu item based on what is shown in the url-bar, or similar. You can of course still compare the URL with the menu, and if they match (or match a setup in an array or similar) add a class to it, with the background.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie how may I be able to achieve that? Do you think you can provide an example?

Comment: Eh... no. I dunno what kind of server-side language you're using, if any, and no, I won't write a whole menu-system for you. But you can find plenty of PHP-examples online, both here and via Google (I'm just assuming that you're using PHP, if you're using something else, just substitute PHP with whatever server-side language you have available). You can even do it with javascript/jQuery - search for "display active menu item with jQuery" - it should give some hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change  button background image  on click using jquery-**
check Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".menu-trigger").click(function() {
        
     $(".menu-trigger").toggleClass("open")

  })

})
```

```css
.menu-trigger {
    background-image:url("http://download.seaicons.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-2/512/usb-icon.png");
    background-position:center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    left:0%;
    transform:rotate(-135deg);
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer
}

.open{
  background-image:url("http://download.seaicons.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-2/512/help-desk-icon.png");
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-wrapper">
      <div class="header">
          <a><div class="menu-trigger" title="Menu"></div></a>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the background image for each in a class, then just toggle?

```
.pre_click { 
     background-image:url(".../image_1.png");
 }
.post_click { 
     background-image:url(".../image_2.png");
 }
```

Then toggle

```
 $('.menu').on('click', function() { 
    $('.menu').toggleClass('pre_click post_click')
})
```

Make sure you set the default class that you want applied to the 'menu' item so it will properly toggle.

Comment: For anyone else looking for this solution, you have to put the JS code above twice for both CSS classes